# Need sql to generate output as shown in expected result in json array

Tags: json, sql-server

My SQL server
Query

```sql
DECLARE @json NVarChar(max)='{
    "LoginName" : "SystemLogin",
    "Authenticationtype" : "Windows",
    "Roles":[ "bulkadmin", "setupadmin", "diskadmin" ],
    "Pages":["SignUp","Login","ForgotPassword"] 
    }'
 
select LoginName,AuType,PageName,RoleName from OPENJSON(@json)
WITH
( 
    LoginName VARCHAR(20) '$.LoginName' ,
    AuType VARCHAR(20) '$.Authenticationtype',
    Pages nvarchar(MAX)  '$.Pages' AS JSON,
    Roles nvarchar(MAX)  '$.Roles' AS JSON
)
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(Pages) WITH 
(
    PageName VARCHAR(20) '$'
)
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(Roles) WITH 
(
    RoleName VARCHAR(20) '$'
)
```

Here is OutPut

[image]

I want Expected Result

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Check out [ask]. This question definitely needs more details about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Neither of those images demonstrate JSON. What does desiring JSON have to do with the non-JSON dataset you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `OPENJSON()` with default schema when you parse `$.Pages` and `$.Roles` JSON arrays:

JSON:

```
DECLARE @json NVarChar(max)='{
    "LoginName" : "SystemLogin",
    "Authenticationtype" : "Windows",
    "Roles":[ "bulkadmin", "setupadmin", "diskadmin" ],
    "Pages":["SignUp","Login","ForgotPassword"] 
}'
```

Statement:

```
SELECT LoginName, AuType, p.[value] AS PageName, r.[value] AS RoleName
FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH ( 
    LoginName VARCHAR(20) '$.LoginName' ,
    AuType VARCHAR(20) '$.Authenticationtype',
    Pages nvarchar(MAX)  '$.Pages' AS JSON,
    Roles nvarchar(MAX)  '$.Roles' AS JSON
) 
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(Pages) p
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(Roles) r
WHERE p.[key] = r.[key]
```

Result:

```
LoginName   AuType  PageName        RoleName
----------------------------------------------
SystemLogin Windows SignUp          bulkadmin
SystemLogin Windows Login           setupadmin
SystemLogin Windows ForgotPassword  diskadmin
```

Answer (score 0):

..plagiarizing.. upvote the original author/source (@Zhorov)

```
DECLARE @json NVarChar(max)='{
    "LoginName" : "SystemLogin",
    "Authenticationtype" : "Windows",
    "Roles":[ "bulkadmin", "setupadmin", "diskadmin" ],
    "Pages":["SignUp","Login","ForgotPassword", "Page1", "Page2"] 
}';
/*
    "Roles":[ "bulkadmin", "setupadmin", "diskadmin", "Role1", "Role2", "Role3" ],
    "Pages":["SignUp","Login","ForgotPassword"] 
*/
/*
    "Roles":[],
    "Pages":[] 
*/

SELECT LoginName, AuType, pr.PageName, pr.RoleName
FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH ( 
    LoginName VARCHAR(20) '$.LoginName' ,
    AuType VARCHAR(20) '$.Authenticationtype',
    Pages nvarchar(MAX)  '$.Pages' AS JSON,
    Roles nvarchar(MAX)  '$.Roles' AS JSON
) as oj
outer apply
(
    select p.value as PageName, r.value as RoleName
    from
    (
        select *
        from OPENJSON(oj.Pages)
    ) as p
    full outer join
    (
        select *
        from OPENJSON(oj.Roles)
    ) as r on p.[key] = r.[key]
) as pr;
```

Comment: Both query gives the same result as per my expected result thank you.

Comment: ..@Dhaval, you might get slightly different results when the two arrays "Roles" & "Pages" have different number of values, eg.`"Roles":[ "bulkadmin" ], "Pages": ["SignUp","Login","ForgotPassword"] `